# Startup Repair - How to emulate it without running it

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, boot

Curious question, may sound odd or foolish.

Im making the assumption that startup repair uses some sort of cmd commands. I am curious as to what they are.

Most of the time, if I have a boot/partition issue, I just use bcdedit or bootrec.
Today I had a particular issue that wasnt resolvable using those commands. I had to use startup repair. I would like to be able to do whatever startup repair does in the future but in cmd.

Does that make sense? Can anyone help me out?

I wasnt able to find any documentation that specifically explained cmd commands or such.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't me asking, why?  Do you not *trust* the `Startup Repair` utility?  Personally, I really like to see how things work within Windows, also... but not to the point where I could conceivably make the fix-actions occur much more slowly.

Comment: From what I know, alternative way in order to check and repair your hard drive through cmd is "chkdisk" command.

Comment: I do trust it, but i like to leave the power in my hands and not the tools available to me. that way if i lose access to those tools i can still accomplish it. make sense? probably not, just how i am as a person